# Java 8: Transform EnumMap<ExampleEnum, String> to Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, java-8, maps, java-stream, enum-map

I have a situation where I need to copy my `EnumMap<ExampleEnum,String>` to `Map<String, Object>`. Many examples on Stack Overflow shows how to cast from one data type to another but not from enum. I have tried doing it through stream but no luck. Here is my code

```
private enum Number{
  One, Two, Three;
}
final Map<Number, String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new EnumMap<Number, String> (Number.class));

populateMap(map);
Map<String, Object> newMap= new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Now I want to do something like

```
newMap.putAll(map);
```

How can I do it through Stream APIs?

Comment: What data should result map hold? I am guessing that String should be name of enum, but what should be held under Object value?

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Object> newMap = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString(),  Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

A more concise answer is,

```
final Map<Number, String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new EnumMap<>(Number.class));

Map<String, Object> newMap= new HashMap<>();

map.forEach((key, value) -> newMap.put(key.name(), value));
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank You :)